# How to apply same keyframes properties on mupltiple strips in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I do video editing in blender for youtube, and I find my self repeating same stuff again and again because I don't know how do I apply same keyframe properties to multiple strips and it became very time consuming. It takes me an entire day to just finish a video.

for example.

I want to provide subtitle using images which I make in inkscape.
now for every single subtitle strip I have to apply keyframes separately, like multiply. stretching etc. same goes for title and transition for the foreground images, because my video consist of mostly images (ken burns effect)

I know I can Apply same properties to multiple strips by selecting multiple strip and setting value and then right mouse click and select "apply to selected". can I do same with keyframes because those strips shares same keyframe value (except for the position of the strip)

is it possible to apply keyframes to multiple strip?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about editing multiple strips, but did you know that [Leon Cheung](http://blender.stackexchange.com/users/696/leon-cheung) created a [Subtitle Importer](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350296-Addon-Animation-Nodes&p=3029932&viewfull=1#post3029932) using the [Animation Nodes add-on](http://www.blendernation.com/2015/03/17/review-animation-nodes-addon/)? I haven't had any projects yet requiring subtitling, but if I do, that will be the first thing I'll try.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I don't have any idea about addons and It's not all about subtitles only, but I will consider this if I can not find any great solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html

Keying sets might have what you are looking for, although I do not know how to apply them to vse strips as its not stated how or if you can. Sorry if that's not helpful.

Comment: There are addons like the "VSE quick functions", which allow you to easily apply a customized fade-in fade-out to any strips (whether you select them all at once, or one by one and just click apply the preset setting once per strip; use for text!). I think the answer really lies in creating scripts to automate what you need, definitely seems possible given these addons do the same stuff. "VSE transform tool" is very worth having on all the time, it'll speed up some processes you will likely do. There are still gaps though. I share your issue and would like more tools to address these problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot of ken burns stuff, checkout the [VSE_Transform_Tools](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools) add-on. There's a [function](https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools#Call_Menu) called "Call Menu" that lets you insert a keyframe from a menu that will apply keyframes to multiple selected strips at once. Alternatively, you can enable the automatic keyframe button.

The [Subsimport](https://github.com/doakey3/Subsimport) add-on will let you import subtitles into Blender and provides nice shortcuts for setting their in and out times. You can then export to a .srt file. You could then use ffmpeg to burn the subtitles into the video with any font (follow [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo) guide for that)